# Al guardar una frase en string, solo me guarda la primer palabra

Tags: java

Cuando guardo una frase en un String, solo me guarda la primer palabra.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

**Código del cliente:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String fraseResult;
        try(ServerSocket socketServidor = new ServerSocket(PORT)){
        while(true) {

                System.out.println("Esperant connexions....");

            try (Socket connexio = socketServidor.accept();
                    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(connexio.getInputStream());
                    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connexio.getOutputStream());) {


                System.out.println("Conexxio acepted...");  

                String fraseRebut = input.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Missatge rebut:" + fraseRebut);
                output.writeUTF(fraseRebut + "des del servidor");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Código del servidor:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner lec =new Scanner(System.in);
                int port = 8080;

                try(Socket socket = new Socket(HOST,PORT);
                        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());){


                    String frase=lec.next();
                    String fraseRebut=frase.toUpperCase();
                    output.writeUTF(fraseRebut);
                    fraseRebut = input.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Missatge rebut:" + fraseRebut);

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor, dinos dónde es el problema en sí, de lo contrario tendremos que leer todo el código y tratar de adivinar cómo funciona para luego tratar de adivinar dónde está el problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualmente estás utilizando el método **next()** para leer la entrada de datos, esta operación solo lee datos hasta encontrar un delimitador de palabras como por ejemplo "espacio" por eso solo lee la primera palabra, para leer la frase completa deberías utilizar **nextLine()**